# Rails with Simple Form - Styling

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have two current problems.

I have a _form in my app which has 5 checkbox criteria and then two yes/no questions.

My first problem is that I want to indent the check box so that it is neatly aligned with the other content in the form (rather than to the left of the labels on the other questions. Does anyone know how to do this?

My next problem is that I can't make my simple form pick up my css styling when incorporated like this?

```
 <%= f.label  :ethics,  'Does this project require ethics approval?', {:class=> "sub-question"}  %>
```

When I inspect the element in google, the font, colour and size are all struck out. Does anyone know how to apply this CSS?

Thank you

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Is the CSS is not loaded or is the class not applied?

Comment: The CSS for font, colour and size is struck out and not applied. The remaining components are applied. I don't know how to bring the checkboxes into alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= f.label "Does this project require ethics approval?", :class => 'sub-question'%>
```

You are trying both `:ethics` and  `'Does this project require ethics approval?'` for label field name that is why the `css` is not loading

Comment: Hi Avishek, I don't think that's the problem - ethic's is the attribute that holds the answer. It needs to be there, the padding and margin components of CSS class 'sub-question' are being applied, but the font, colour and size are not. In google I can inspect element and see that they are struck out and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I tried this - but it doesn't pick up the css. Any idea as to where I can find examples?

Comment: I'm not getting what you want, what your `:ethics` will contain, as it's a simple label?

Comment: Thanks - I had to add !important to the attributes. You were right that it was going to the style, but all the elements were being struck out. I can't find how to add the order of the CSS tree in a way that lets my tree override the simple form defaults, but !important works for now. Thank you.